# How do you translate EXT:Form Buttons in TYPO3 CMS 8.7 LTS?

Tags: forms, typo3, translation, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

with the topic [How do you translate EXT:Form forms in TYPO3 CMS 8.7 LTS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44628751/how-do-you-translate-extform-forms-in-typo3-cms-8-7-lts) i got my translations almost complete. Can anyone help me to also translate the prevous and next buttons in the forms?

f.e.

```
renderables:
  -
    renderingOptions:
      previousButtonLabel: ''
      nextButtonLabel: ''
    identifier: page-1
    label: ''
    type: Page
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following translation keys to translate buttons in EXT:form.

```
element.Form.renderingOptions.submitButtonLabel
element.Page.renderingOptions.previousButtonLabel
element.Page.renderingOptions.nextButtonLabel
element.SummaryPage.renderingOptions.previousButtonLabel
element.SummaryPage.renderingOptions.nextButtonLabel
```

These allow to localize button labels **globally** for all forms equally.

---

You can set translated custom labels for **specific** forms, too. Please mind the special position of the form-identifier inside the translation key only for the *submit* button (seems a bug):

```
element.<form-identifier>.renderingOptions.submitButtonLabel
```

To translate *previous* and *next* buttons for specific forms, you can use the element-identifiers. You can also combine these with a form-identifier.

Form definition (excerpt):

```
renderables:
  -
    renderingOptions:
      previousButtonLabel: 'Previous step'
      nextButtonLabel: 'Next step'
    identifier: summarypage-1
    label: 'Summary page'
    type: SummaryPage
```

Translation keys:

```
<form-identifier>.element.<element-identifier>.renderingOptions.nextButtonLabel
element.<element-identifier>.renderingOptions.nextButtonLabel
<form-identifier>.element.<element-identifier>.renderingOptions.previousButtonLabel
element.<element-identifier>.renderingOptions.previousButtonLabel
```

Example keys for the form definition above:

```
MyContactForm.element.summarypage-1.renderingOptions.previousButtonLabel
element.summarypage-1.renderingOptions.previousButtonLabel
```

---

Limitation: You can **not** translate *previous* and *next* buttons when combining the `form-identifier` and the general `element-type` (like 'SummaryPage').

The following won't work:

```
<form-identifier>.element.SummaryPage.renderingOptions.nextButtonLabel
```

Comment: Thanks! Helped me a lot.