# TYPO3 xliff localisation in extension ist not working as expected

Tags: localization, typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions, xliff

I currently trying to localize some Webforms. which are made with TYPO3 v8 forms_formframework.

The Frontend shows always the translated label, it ignores the selected Language.

locallang.xlf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xliff version="1.0" xmlns:t3="http://typo3.org/schemas/xliff">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="messages" product-name="dm_layout">
        <header/>
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="kontaktformular.element.text-1.properties.placeholder" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Original</source>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

de.locallang.xlf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xliff version="1.0" xmlns:t3="http://typo3.org/schemas/xliff">
    <file source-language="en" target-language="de" datatype="plaintext" original="messages" product-name="dm_layout">
        <header/>
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="kontaktformular.element.text-1.properties.placeholder" xml:space="preserve">
                        <target>Kontakt DE</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

languages.ts (Typoscript is loading correctly)

```
config.language = de
config.sys_language_uid = 0
config.locale_all = de_DE.utf8

[globalVar = GP:L=1]
    config.language = en
    config.sys_language_uid = 1
    config.locale_all = en_GB.utf8
[global]
```

The English page should show: Original

The German page should show: Kontakt DE

But both restuling in 'Kontakt DE'

I did almost the same as [How do you translate EXT:Form forms in TYPO3 CMS 8.7 LTS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44628751/how-do-you-translate-extform-forms-in-typo3-cms-8-7-lts)

Answer (score 1):

In your de.localland.xlf try instead:

```
<trans-unit id="kontaktformular.element.text-1.properties.placeholder">
    <source> Original </source>
    <target>Kontakt DE</target>
</trans-unit>
```

Comment: For some unknown Reason the result is still the same.

Comment: IMHO the source is not necessary for the translation within TYPO3 itself, still it is a convenience feature for human translators, which will have the source available together with the desired target, so they actually know what should have been translated, while correcting translations.