# Translate EXT:form validator in TYPO3 8.7

Tags: forms, validation, typo3, translation, typo3-9.x

I've got a problem with translating the client side validator in ext:form in a multi language site en/de/it/fr/cn.

But in english page I have the german translation "Bitte füllen Sie dieses Feld aus", which should not appear here.

I tried all variations of

```
support.validation.error.email.1221560910

validation.error.1221560910
```

in typo3conf/ext/site_package/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf but nothing happens with german message...

I've already tried [How do you translate EXT:Form forms in TYPO3 CMS 8.7 LTS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44628751/how-do-you-translate-extform-forms-in-typo3-cms-8-7-lts)

Answer (score 1):

You can translate validation error messages with the following translation keys:

```
<formDefinitionIdentifier>.validation.error.<elementIdentifier>.<validationErrorCode>
<formDefinitionIdentifier>.validation.error.<validationErrorCode>
validation.error.<elementIdentifier>.<validationErrorCode>
validation.error.<validationErrorCode>
```

Source: [Documentation of the TYPO3 Form Framework, TYPO3 v8](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/8.7/en-us/Concepts/FrontendRendering/Index.html#translation-of-validation-messages)

**Important:** the translation keys for validation messages are only considered if you don't already have a `message` in the form definition under `validationErrorMessages`!

So please check your form definition for custom validation messages and remove them there.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to define the current language in your typoscript.

instead of the older condition based on the L-parameter you now need it done with the symphony expressions:

```
[siteLanguage("title") == "English"]
  config {
      sys_language_uid = 1
      language = en
      locale_all = en_US.UTF-8
      htmlTag_langKey = en
  }
[global]
```

and you need the correct spelling based on your language definition in the yaml file

Comment: is this for 9.5? I have accidentally spoken in the subject of 9.5, but the project runs under 8.7

Comment: TYPO3 9 differs from TYPO3 8. The language handling has changed and also the form extension is different. As you mentioned TYPO3 9.5 in your headline I assumed a TYPO3 9 project.

Comment: It is recommended in TYPO3 v9 (and above) to remove all language related TypoScript. Using a Site Configuration will replace the former TypoScript settings. See https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/9.5/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/AddLanguages.html